# Media Foundation - cross platform audio sync issue when creating MP4

Tags: video, mp4, ms-media-foundation

Using MS Media Foundation, I'm attempting to create a video (H.264/AAC) from image frames, and add an audio track consisting of sound effects at various places.  There will be gaps in the audio stream between sound effects.  I'm using an `IMFSinkWriter` configured with an audio and video stream (details below).  I'm currently testing with just a single sound effect placed 2 seconds into the video.  The MP4 file renders without error, and plays correctly (sound effect plays at correct location) under Windows (via Windows Media Player or "Movies & TV").  However, when I play the video under MacOS (QuickTime), the audio is not synced correctly.  The sound effect occurs much earlier than expected.

**Details**

My `SinkWriter` is configured with a video stream, with output subtype `MFVideoFormat_H264`, and input subtype `MFVideoFormat_RGB32`.  The audio stream is configured with output subtype `MFAudioFormat_AAC` and input subtype `MFAudioFormat_PCM` (matching the `IMFSourceReader` providing the audio samples).

I write all the video frames first, and then write the audio samples.  When writing the audio, I use `SendStreamTick` (every 0.5 seconds) when there are gaps in the audio, both before and after the sound effect.  I also set `MFSampleExtension_Discontinuity` on the first audio sample.  I  also tried sending `NotifyEndOfSegment` after the sound effect, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I don't write a sample description box because I believe that it is auto-generated for my configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Open in the suitable video editor and check timing for video and audio tracks. May be you have more frames than sync audio track. Also check frame duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The MP4 file renders without error, and plays correctly (sound effect plays at correct location) under Windows (via Windows Media Player or "Movies & TV"). However, when I play the video under MacOS (QuickTime), the audio is not synced correctly. The sound effect occurs much earlier than expected.

Different players handle track gaps differently and quite so often they fail to maintain good sync between tracks. More confusingly, they do it in different ways: some skip the gap while staying in sync, other keep playing "master" track smoothly while ignoring the gap on another track.

That is, even if a file is created with correct data timings, it might so happen and it does happen that players fail to play it well.

The best strategy to produce files well-playable on all players is to avoid gaps in video and audio track data. For audio, encoding artificial silence is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that seems to work just fine.  My solution was to write silence (zeros) to the audio stream, instead of using `SetStreamTick`.

Comment: +1 for solving own issue. Regarding _"input subtype `MFAudioFormat_PCM`"_ you should do a quick read up on how PCM and sampling works. Writing samples with zero value in PCM data for silence (padding) is expected solution. You got it!! The only mystery now is _" plays correctly... under Windows (via W.M.Player)"_, is Microsoft really that good?

Comment: Thanks @VC.One!  Seems like the MS players handle stream ticks differently than other players (as mentioned in @Roman 's answer).  Thanks again!